# How to use colspan in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am building an app using Angular 2 and Bootstrap. My code is like below,

```
<div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th style="width: 50%">Away Team Statistics</th>
              <th style="width: 50%;">Home Team Statistics</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Team Name</th>
              <th>Games Played</th>
              <th>Wins</th>
              <th>Loses</th>
              <th>Draw</th>
              <th>Points</th>
              <th>Goals</th>
              <th>Goals Against</th>
              <th>Goal Difference</th>
              <!-- Away Stats-->
              <th>Wins</th>              
              <th>Loses</th>
              <th>Draw</th>
              <th>Goals</th>
              <th>Goals Against</th>

              <!-- Home Stats-->
              <th>Wins</th>              
              <th>Loses</th>
              <th>Draw</th>
              <th>Goals</th>
              <th>Goals Against</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let league of leagues">
              <td>{{league.position}}</td>
              <td> <img [src]="league.crestURI" [alt]="league.teamName" width="20px" height="20px"><a href="#" (click)="getTeams(league._links.team.href, league.teamName); showPlayers == true">{{league.teamName}}</a>                </td>
              <td>{{league.playedGames}}</td>
              <td>{{league.wins}}</td>
              <td>{{league.losses}}</td>
              <td>{{league.draws}}</td>
              <td>{{league.points}}</td>
              <td>{{league.goals}}</td>
              <td>{{league.goalsAgainst}}</td>
              <td>{{league.goalDifference}}</td>
              <!-- Away Stats-->
              <td>{{league.away.wins}}</td>
              <td>{{league.away.losses}}</td>
              <td>{{league.away.draws}}</td>
              <td>{{league.away.goals}}</td>
              <td>{{league.away.goalsAgainst}}</td>

              <!-- Away Stats-->
              <td>{{league.home.wins}}</td>
              <td>{{league.home.losses}}</td>
              <td>{{league.home.draws}}</td>
              <td>{{league.home.goals}}</td>
              <td>{{league.home.goalsAgainst}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Now when it loads the columns which are under the `Away Team Statistics` or `Home Team Statistics` gets outside the panel. It is due to variable number of columns may be. I have attached the screenshot for better understanding.
[image: Screenshot]

I want that the portion which gets outside of the `panel/table` should appear within the panel. `width:100%` or `colspan="5"` both are not working. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The inline style on last two columns of table is wrong.

```
style="width: 50%"
```

Either add a bootstrap provided class `table-responsive` to your table or set a width to your table using:

```
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill your `div.panel-body` with 12 column table you must add `overflow-x: scrollbar` to `div` or just format your table from the start with 5 columns. The table with 12 columns can have [weird look](https://jsfiddle.net/vqbgqrm5/). Also, you can use `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags, they are very useful for understanding the code.